# Unable to execute grep command in script while passing the string to be searched as variable

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to run following script but unable to run the find/grep command successfully as the variable in grep command is causing an issue. Can someone please help what wrong I am doing while passing the variable in grep. Basically I am reading an input from the file and passing that in grep.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE_FOLDER='20220922'
while IFS= read -r line
do 
name="$line"
echo "Name read from file - $name"
echo $name
find /ABC/XXX/$DATE_FOLDER*/ -type f -exec grep -l "'${name}'" {} \; >> fileNameList.txt

done < TestInput.txt
sort -u fileNameList.txt >> finalNameList.txt
```

Comment: What kind of problems/issue? Did you tried a different `fd` for read?

Comment: I want to execute the below command. This runs fine if I run it as single command but not via the script that I posted in the question.                           
find /ABC/XXX/$DATE_FOLDER*/ -type f -exec grep -l 'BN-5113580412' {} \;

Comment: Have you tried a different `fd` for read? Are there any empty lines? in the text file? Is there any carriage returns in the files?...

Comment: Did you tried to debug, via `set -x` ? Also the file name has single quotes? like `"'${name}'"`

Comment: no empty lines in text file and it does not have any single quotes

Comment: I tried "while read line" but still no success

Comment: remove the single quotes from `"'${name}'"`

Comment: tried no success

Comment: Looks like just `grep -rlf TestInput.txt /ABC/XXX/$DATE_FOLDER*/ | sort -u`